# Need to convert Windows Console Application class to ISynchronizeInvoke object

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, console-application

I am new to Threading and Synchronizing concepts in VB.Net.

Presently I am working on converting a Windows Form application to Console application. 
Form application uses a DLL which which is used for Async process:

```
    public ProcessCaller(ISynchronizeInvoke isi)
        : base(isi)
    {

    }
```

But now when I convert this form application to Console application, I am not able to pass console application class to this DLL.

I am getting error "Not able to cast from 'X' to 'Y'"

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say you're working in VB.NET, but the code snippet is C#...?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Yes i am working on VB.net code which calls the DLL which is written in C#.
I am calling this method in VB Code:
x = New AsyncProcess.ProcessCaller(Me)

Which is giving me runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

`ISynchronizeInvoke` is used to get back to the "right" thread, typically in client apps where all UI operations need to be on the same thread. This is usually done via a message pump / event loop - which typically doesn't exist in a console app?

What are your threading requirements in the console app? If you don't have any, you can probably write your own no-op implementation of `ISynchronizeInvoke` which always returns `false` from `InvokeRequired` etc. Here's a first attempt at an implementation - untested, mind you...

```
public class NoOpSynchronizeInvoke : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private delegate object GeneralDelegate(Delegate method,
                                            object[] args);

    public bool InvokeRequired { get { return false; } }

    public Object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method,
                                    object[] args)
    {
        GeneralDelegate x = Invoke;
        return x.BeginInvoke(method, args, null, x);
    }

    public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        GeneralDelegate x = (GeneralDelegate) result.AsyncState;
        return x.EndInvoke(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: John, Thank you for you quick response.

I have project which is written using Threading concepts for Win form application. Now i am trying to separate the UI part of it to convert it to Console application.

Can please write the above code in VB.Net.

Thanks

Comment: @user2060435: No, I'm afraid not. I don't have the time. You can either do it yourself - there are plenty of VB/C# converters around - or you can just build it into a C# DLL which you reference from your C# project.